# How to use numpy to generate random numbers on segmentation intervals

Tags: python, numpy

I am using numpy module in python to generate random numbers. When I need to generate random numbers in a continuous interval such as [a,b], I will use

```
(b-a)*np.random.rand(1)+a
```

but now I Need to generate a uniform random number in the interval [a, b] and [c, d], what should I do?

I want to generate a random number that is uniform over the length of all the intervals. I do not select an interval with equal probability, and then generate a random number inside the interval. If [a, b] and [c, d] are equal in length, There is no problem with this use, but when the lengths of the intervals are not equal, the random numbers generated by this method are not completely uniform.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html

Comment: If `[a,b]` and [`c,d`] have different lengths should 1) either interval be chosen with equal prob? or 2) should they be chosen with prob proprtional to their respective lengths?

Comment: It may be that I did not make it clear that the resulting random number should be uniform over the length of the total interval. In other words, the probability of selecting a certain interval should be related to the length of the interval.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like

```
a,b,c,d = 1,2,7,9
N = 10
r = np.random.uniform(a-b,d-c,N)
r += np.where(r<0,b,c)
r
# array([7.30557415, 7.42185479, 1.48986144, 7.95916547, 1.30422703,
#        8.79749665, 8.19329762, 8.72669862, 1.88426196, 8.33789181])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
np.random.uniform(a,b)
```

for your random numbers between a and b (including a but excluding b)

So for random number in [a,b] and [c,d], you can use

```
np.random.choice( [np.random.uniform(a,b) , np.random.uniform(c,d)] )
```

Comment: It uses numpy. It is actually a method of numpy

Comment: Well now that you edited it to actually use `numpy` I'll give you a point XD

Comment: Actually I thought it is obvious that random method is of numpy. I always use numpy's random method. My bad.

Comment: I suddenly found that the random numbers generated in this way are not completely uniform. According to my original expectation, the random number should be generated uniformly in the total interval, but the random number generated by this method varies in length between the two segments. Not evenly

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recipe:

```
def random_multiinterval(*intervals, shape=(1,)):
    # FIXME assert intervals are valid and non-overlapping
    size = sum(i[1] - i[0] for i in intervals)
    v = size * np.random.rand(*shape)
    res = np.zeros_like(v)
    for i in intervals:
        res += (0 < v) * (v < (i[1] - i[0])) * (i[0] + v)
        v -= i[1] - i[0]
    return res

In [11]: random_multiinterval((1, 2), (3, 4))
Out[11]: array([1.34391171])

In [12]: random_multiinterval((1, 2), (3, 4), shape=(3, 3))
Out[12]:
array([[1.42936024, 3.30961893, 1.01379663],
       [3.19310627, 1.05386192, 1.11334538],
       [3.2837065 , 1.89239373, 3.35785566]])
```

Note: This is uniformly distributed over N (non-overlapping) intervals, even if they have different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You can just assign a probability for how likely it will be [a,b] or [c,d] and then generate accordingly:

```
import numpy as np
import random

random_roll = random.random()
a = 1
b = 5
c = 7
d = 10
if random_roll > .5: # half the time we will use [a,b]
    my_num = (b - a) * np.random.rand(1) + a
else: # the other half we will use [c,d]
    my_num = (d - c) * np.random.rand(1) + c
print(my_num)
```